# SOLR small word search issue

Tags: php, solr

We have implemented SOLR for a client, but we have issues with small word in the query. For example if we search for **Vitamine D3** with:

```
search_name:(vitamine^4 AND d3)
```

we also get products that don't have D3 in the title.
It's strange that if we search only for d3 with:

```
search_name:(d3)
```

we don't get any results.
We tried to add d3 in protwords.txt, but then, both queries don't return anything.

Without adding D3 in protwords.txt:

[print screen 1](https://prnt.sc/IfRKOpOPOxMF)

[print screen 2](https://prnt.sc/0TLPAECzMQum)

[print screen 3](https://prnt.sc/f4oAIl33DPG4)

After adding D3 in protwords.txt:

[print screen 4](https://prnt.sc/5IzoZPxR8SME)

[print screen 5](https://prnt.sc/j4KbtgG7VE0b)

Did anyone had the same issue, how did you manage to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: whats the field type applied for you field? Did you by any chance checked the behaviour on the solr analysis page?

Comment: Please add any images using the built-in support on stack overflow; external links tend to vanish over time and make questions unusable. Also try to avoid using images as much as possible, as they're not searchable and have bad accessibility.

Comment: You might want to add the `debugQuery` parameter to your queries and look at the `debug/explain` output to see why these records were matched: https://hectorcorrea.com/blog/solr-debugquery/2021-11-11-00001

Comment: It is strange that your first screenshot shows the word "d3" being indexed as two tokens "d" and "3". It would be good to know the definition of your "search_name" field, it seems to be using the WDGF https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_4/filter-descriptions.html#word-delimiter-graph-filter and might explain why you are seeing these results.